# Flash usb grub fail, grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

When installing from the flash usb I was told a bootloader could not be installed. I chose the *continue without bootloader* option. When I restarted without the usb I faced a blank screen flashing cursor. I rebooted with the flash usb and installed and ran boot-repair. Then I restarted without the usb but this time I got the "grub rescue" screen. I get the feeling my partitions are messed up as I can't seem to follow any advice I google because nothing exists, or is named very oddly e.g. `/dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p5` rather than `/dev/sda`. It may be to do wth using usb rather than dvd to install. Here is what a sudo fdisk -l returns

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo fdisk -l
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: invalid flag 0x91e6 of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

Disk /dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b8aa8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1             512      500223      249856   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          500734   250081791   124790529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5   ?  1454279609  3201150582   873435487   b7  BSDI fs

Disk /dev/sdb: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0: 128.0 GB, 128041877504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250081792 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b8aa8

                              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1             512      500223      249856   83  Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p2          500734   250081791   124790529    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p5          500736   250081791   124790528   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1: 255 MB, 255852544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31 cylinders, total 499712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
fdisk: unable to read /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[/code]
```

Here is the [boot-repair report](http://paste2.org/NB0XN48X)

My question is how can I install Grub manually from live usb? I have tried to do this but it always seems to fail, for example I follow the instructions (http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) but firstly /dev/sd does not seem to exist for me. So from looking at gparted I use

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1 /mnt
```

or `/mnt/boot`

then the following issues a problem

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/mapper/isw_ciehbafdfa_Volume0p1 
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install.real: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install.real: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install.real: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution to your problem, but I had a similar issue two months ago when I replaced Arch with Ubuntu. For some reason the installer tried to install the bootloader on my USB instead of my HDD :P Try and manually install the grub bootloader after the installation :p

Comment: Hi thank you. I too have installed arch on a different computer. I have tried what you suggested but I am having difficulty. I gather I need to remount--I have detailed the issues much better on the Mint forum.

Comment: The link is [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=185980)

Comment: What filesystem are you using? ext2 or ext3?

Comment: Also check this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks I provided the boot-repair report above. I am still having great difficulty finding any remedy. Any suggestions would really help! I think I've tried everything. Including a different flash usb and still having issues. Is there more information I could provide that would help others to help me?

Comment: That is so weird.. I'm sorry but I have no idea then, try another forum (maybe Arch linux forum)